# Postgresql rsync synchronization of replica using rsync -u

Tags: postgresql

It is safe to synchronize PostgreSQL replication using the rsync parameter -u?

For example if my replication was lost for a long time due to connection problem (WAL archive already deleted for example), I always need to rsync all the files of my database again from the master to the replica.

So I am using something like (or almost like) this (inside slave):

```
systemctl stop postgresql@11-slave 
psql -h 10.0.0.MASTER -Atc "select pg_start_backup('clone', true);"
rsync -avz user@10.0.0.MASTER:/var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/lib/postgresql/11/  
systemctl start postgresql@11-slave 
psql -h 10.0.0.MASTER -Atc "select pg_stop_backup('clone', true);"
```

The solution above is working very fine and tested a lot of times without any data loss.

**But** I am tempted to try to restore the replication using something **faster** (dangerous?) like :

```
systemctl stop postgresql@11-slave 
psql -h 10.0.0.MASTER -Atc "select pg_start_backup('clone', true);"
rsync -uavz user@10.0.0.MASTER:/var/lib/postgresql/11/main/ /var/lib/postgresql/11/  
systemctl start postgresql@11-slave 
psql -h 10.0.0.MASTER -Atc "select pg_stop_backup('clone', true);"
```

Is it safe to use the parameter -u on rsync (update) instead of recopying all the files or should I keep copying all the files when something happen with my replication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that `rsync -u` would buy you anything. The only relevant file that could have a later timestamp on the standby would be the control file, which is small.

I think that this is a classical case of premature optimization. If anything, it can harm you. If by accident someone or something touched a file on the standby, giving it a later timestamp (with or without modifying the contents), you would mistakenly not copy that file, which might well cause data corruption.

You didn't ask about that, but your way of fixing the standby server is dated, since it uses the “exclusive backup API” and relies on `backup_label` being created on the primary's data directory. This backup method was removed in PostgreSQL v15, because a crash on the primary while the backup mode is active has a good chance of putting the primary in a condition where it cannot be restarted without manual intervention. You can change your procedure to use the “non-exclusive backup API”, but it will become quite a bit more complicated.

I recommend that you take the usual measures that reliably prevent the standby server from “dropping out”: either set `restore_command` on the standby to enable it to recover from the WAL archive or use a replication slot and monitor replication.

Comment: First of all thank you very much for your answer! I am using Postgresql 11 in some systems. That is why I am using this approach.